# Ways to determine (or estimate) the weight function that makes trig functions orthogonal on a given interval?

Tags: orthogonality

From the general definition of orthogonality for functions set of trig functions $\phi_k=\cos(kx)$ is orthogonal on $[a,b]$ if

\begin{equation}
\int_a^b w(x) \cos(jx)\cos(kx) dx =\alpha_j \delta_{jk},
\end{equation}

where $w(x)$ is the weight function and $\delta_{jk}$ is the Dirac delta. On the interval $a=-\pi, b=\pi$, $\cos(kx)$ is orthogonal with just $w(x) = 1$. This value of $w(x)$ also works for intervals that are just integer multiples of a $[-\pi, \pi]$.

Are there ways to determine or estimate $w(x)$ for an arbitrary given interval? Say, I want to make them orthogonal on the interval $[0,5]$, what would I do to find $w(x)$ that makes this works?

I'm aware that there are methods of doing so for certain classes of polynomials, but I haven't found anything that discusses trying to do so for trig functions. As far as I am aware, there is no reason why, given $a$ and $b$, there shouldn't be a weight function that works to make the trig functions orthogonal on that interval. Am I mistaken in this and that is not generally possible?

Comment: A preliminary remark : As weight functions make sense only when they take positive values, you aren't free to take any interval $(a,b)$ : if you take : $(a,b)=(-\pi/6,\pi/6)$ for example, you will not succed to make $\cos(1x)$ orthogonal to $\cos(2x)$ whatever the choice for $w(x)$...

Comment: @JeanMarie This is not true, as $w(x)$ can itself be a function (which can become as complex as needed). For your example, $[a,b]=[-\pi, \pi], j=1, k=2$, if we guess that the weight function is of some form $w(x)=x^2-a$ (maybe there's a simpler one, this was just my first guess), we can plug that into the integral (along with the other values), set it equal to 0, and solve for the value of $a$, which I believe is $(1/180)(-232+36\sqrt{3}\pi+5\pi^2)$. (1/2)

Comment: @JeanMarie Now of course this specific weight function is not going to work for other values of $k$ and $j$. But in principle, for specific $k$ and $j$, the appropriate weight function exists, but it is unknown to me if it is possible to find the appropriate weight function for all $j$ and $k$ on the given interval. (2/2)

Comment: 1) My example is not $(-\pi,\pi)$ but  $(-\pi/6,\pi/6)$ on which both functions $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2x)$ are positive. 2)  About your second comment : having a weight function working for specific $k$ and $j$ isn't the good approach : you will not be able to extend it to any value of $k$ and $j$.

Comment: If you want to do a systematic approach to othogonality with appropriate weight functions, I advise you to have a look at the general framework of the so-called "Sturm-Liouville theory".

Comment: @JeanMarie My apologies, I had a typo in my previous comments, I meant to say $\pm \pi/6$ instead of $\pm \pi$. I invite you to try using the weight function that I indicated and you will see that it works. And yes, that is exactly what I said about the value of $j$ and $k$, it's often trivial to find the appropriate weight function for particular values, but establishing one for general values is the challenge.

Comment: @JeanMarie In regards to your second comment, I am familiar with "Sturm-Liouville theory" in the context of physics where it is used to construct solutions to various classes of differential equations. I confess I'm not aware of how that framework goes any further to establish what the weight function might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe that I have what works as a weight function $w(x)$ to make the set of trig functions orthogonal on a given interval $[a,b]$. I realized that if you linearly transform $x$ so that the interval $[a,b]$ is transformed back into $[-\pi, \pi]$, $a$ and $b$ can be whatever and the orthogonality still holds. The linear transform that accomplishes this is

\begin{equation}
x'=\frac{1}{a-b}(-2 \pi x+ \pi(a+b)),
\end{equation}

Where I am using $x'$ to denote the new transformed x. It follows then that the $w(x)$ that transforms $\cos(jx)\cos(kx)$ into the desired form with the transformed $x$'s is

\begin{equation}
w(x)=\frac{\cos\left(j\frac{-2 \pi x+ \pi(a+b)}{a-b}\right)\cos\left(k\frac{-2 \pi x+ \pi(a+b)}{a-b}\right)}{\cos(jx)\cos(kx)}.
\end{equation}

So the solution to the original question can be summed up as the appropriate weight function that makes the set of trig functions orthogonal on an arbitrary interval is the one that performs a linear transform of the given interval back into $[-\pi, \pi]$.